# To display modal pop up in mvc 4 on click of Actionlink button

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc-4

here is my grid view having acton link to show the pop up on click of actionlink

```
grid.Column("", header: "ToDelete", format: @<text> @Html.ActionLink("Delete", "AllStudentDetails", "Home", new { id = item.idReg }, new { @class="Delete-Student"})</text>)
```

I want to display this division

```
<div id="ModalDeactivateConfirmPopUp" class="modal fade" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="dtModalDeactivateConfirmExtra" aria-hidden="true">
```

my javascript:

```
  $(function () {
  $(".Delete-Student").click(function (e) {
   e.preventDefault();
   $("#ModalDeactivateConfirmPopUp").show();        
});
```

});

my pop up is not displaying help me out

thank you

Answer (score 1):

From Bootstrap documentation:

> Public JavaScript APIs methods should accept an optional options object, a string which
>   targets a particular method, or nothing (which initiates a plugin with
>   default behavior):
>
> ```
> $('#myModal').modal();    // initialized with defaults
> $('#myModal').modal('show')    // initializes and invokes show immediately
> ```

So instead `$("#ModalDeactivateConfirmPopUp").show();` you should use `$("#ModalDeactivateConfirmPopUp").modal('show');`

[JsFiddle Demo](https://jsfiddle.net/dz40tn6n/)